# PHP Text Field value shows incomplete data, only 1 word

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just want to ask why after getting a data from MySQL and trying to put it's value on a textfield:

```
$contractorx = $row['Contractor'];
```

The value of **$contractorx** is "Jose Amadeo Alonzo" which is correct. But when I try to display it in an HTML text field using this code:

```
echo "<p>Contractor: <input type=\"text\" name=\"mdu\" readonly value=$contractorx></p>";
```

The text displayed on the field is only "Jose". Can anyone please help in identifying why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Take a good hard look at the HTML that is being output.

Comment: You need quotes I guess...

Comment: a) You're not putting quotes around the value attribute.  b) You're not escaping the output. c) Are you sure that variable really holds the value you think it holds?

Comment: use echo before using in text to debug it and try to separate html and php as much as possible, like, <p>Contractor: <input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value=<?php echo $contractorx; ?>></p>

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess quotes are very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes to the "value"

```
value=\"$contractorx\"
```

Comment: You *need* HTML escaping too!

Comment: That should be done before putting the data in the database anyway ;]

Comment: No it should not. Data in the database has nothing to do with HTML. You only HTML-escape upon output *into* HTML!

Comment: Don't know, but the way i do it is by sanitizing all the input before inserting in the database, that's why i don't care about htmlentities'ing them

Comment: Then what about if and when you want to use a value from the database *outside* of an HTML context? Like, sending it in a plaintext email? *"Dear Mr. Dolce &amp; Gabana..."* Not very appropriate, is it?

Comment: Not to mention wanting to *search* for data in the database, which becomes a hassle as well...

Comment: You are right, totally valid point, i will consider it when writing new code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Because the result looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value=Foo Bar Baz>
```

The attribute `value` has the single value `Foo`, followed by two more attributes `Bar` and `Baz`. You need to use quotes *and* HTML escape the value correctly, should it itself contain quotes:

```
printf('<input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value="%s">',
       htmlspecialchars($contractorx, ENT_COMPAT));
```

Then the result will correctly look like:

```
<input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value="Foo Bar Baz">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)**:

```
$contractorx = htmlspecialchars($row['Contractor']);
```

and do not forget about quotes:

```
echo "<p>Contractor: <input type=\"text\" name=\"mdu\" readonly value=\"$contractorx\"></p>";
```

Or use single quotes:

```
echo '<p>Contractor: <input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value="'.$contractorx.'"></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sprintf("<p>Contractor: <input type='text' name='mdu' readonly value='%s' /></p>",  $contractorx);
```

Comment: There is no point in having double quotes for that string if you're going to just concatenate the variable.

Comment: @BLaZuRE I do not understand you, but this line works well. you may try it. No end user licence aggreement needed.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<p>Contractor: <input type="text" name="mdu" readonly value="'.$contractorx.'"</p>';
```